# MATLAB: How is it possible to see how much memory was used on a .m file?

Tags: matlab, memory

As the title says, how can we see the memory that was used on a .m file(including functions) on MATLAB? Is there some command or something?
I would like to use it as a metric in my algorithm.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "memory spend" ? Memory used by the execution of a function inside a .m file?

Comment: @AnderBiguri The total memory that was used on a .m file(including functions)

Comment: You can check the task manager and monitor it. In matlab the command 'whos' gives you the size (in bytes) of variables etc

Comment: @A.Visser I already know that, thanks, but is there any other way to do this? I want to use it as an output metric to my program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the command line, execute

```
profile -memory on;
```

and start the Matlab profiler as normal to see memory usage. However, you may need to copy information manually

There may be [some alternatives](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/profiling-matlab-memory-usage), such as `mtic` and `mtoc`, depending on your Matlab version, which may allow feeding the data directly to a non-GUI output.

Comment: `mtic` seems like a fantastic function, I wonder why they didnt continued it

Comment: Thank you, mtic and mtoc do not appear to work on my version. Maybe Matlab profiler along with memory usage may get the job done for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also start the profiler from the Editor Menu (at the top task bar of MATLAB GUI).

When you start the profiler, the codes executes normarly but when it exits/ends then the MATLAB displays all sorts of information that you want.

Including (but not limited to):
execution time
calls made
memory (I think! :P )

Comment: Σε ευχαριστώ φίλε Κώστα :P με τον profiler θα γίνει λογικά η δουλειά!