# Tracking detailed MATLAB memory usage on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: matlab, memory, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to monitor the memory used by MATLAB on an ubuntu 14.04 machine. Using 'top' I can have an idea of the total memory MATLAB is using, but I'm interested in a function that would work like Windows' "memory" function but on ubuntu 14.04 and would give all the memory details.

How can I build such a function, and is it possible in the first place?

Comment: Memory returns different informations. Which of the numbers do you need?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115402/matlab-how-is-it-possible-to-see-how-much-memory-was-used-on-a-m-file/32115664#32115664

Comment: I am most interested in the maximum possible array "largest contiguous free memory block" but, again, on ubuntu

Comment: On a 64bit machine you typically don't run out of address space, which means the available memory and the maximum possible array size should be the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will get you what you need, but the whos function is very useful and works on all platforms. It will create a structure with the "bytes" field which can tell you memory usage by variable. For total memory used, I like:

```
allvars = whos;
memused = sum([allvars.bytes]);
```

This assumes your script/function only uses one workspace. For multiple workspaces, you'll have to call them out specifically. Read the whos documentation for more details of the information you can get from it.